# Decreasing Yield Curve: Infer expected future trend?

Tags: interest-rate

If the yield curve for zero coupon bonds is decreasing does it mean (in general)
that investors are thinking that country's economy has gloomy future? Or unpredictable?

Comment: Please be more clear. Explain what a "zero-coupon bond" is. Also, a "yield curve" is, a curve, a collection of points. In what sense it is "decreasing"? You mean shifted downwards as a whole for all maturities?